# Avoiding multiple executions in xforms-enabled

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to launch a javascript for adding extra functionality to a form run. The script must be launch when the form is loaded.

The idea is:

```
 <xxf:script ev:event="xforms-enabled">
         alert('hello world');           
 </xxf:script>
```

The problem is, as described at the [Orbeon Forum](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Multiple-executions-in-xforms-enabled-in-XBL-components-td3752664.html), the "xforms-enabled" event is launched several times (for each control and variable). In the forum is described some workarounds and solutions, but cannot be applied when using javascript (or I do not know how to do it).

The question is: how can I execute the javascript code only one time when starting the form? Must I use another event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to run your script on `xforms-ready`, which is dispatched to the model. So you would put, inside your `<xf:model>`:

```
<xxf:script ev:event="xforms-ready">...</xxf:script>
```

Comment: It works! thanks. I have already tested the "xforms-ready" event but my error was that I have put it outside the "<xf:model>". Inside the model, it works fine and the alert window is only showed one time.